# Identify this book: boy who was raised by white tiger

Tags: story-identification, novel

I remember reading this book in the early 60s as a teenager.
At the time I thought it was very provocative for a book aimed at a teenager.

I thought that the name was "Tam son of the white tigress", but I have never found any reference to that name online.

Answer (score 6):

Google "Tam son of the white tigress" and you come up with a book entitled : "Tam son of the tiger" with the description: "Tam Evans was carried away by a white tigress when he was two years old. The son of the white tigress!"

Comment: A link might be helpful too: http://www.amazon.com/Tam-Tiger-Otis-Adelbert-Kline/dp/144994972X/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1264435035&sr=1-1

Comment: Thanks for your help. My problem with google was I put quotes around the title and and tigress was not the correct for part of the title. I should have not used the quotes.  Now that I know that this was an Otis Kline store, I checked and remember reading a number of his other works, the Mars work as well as 'Jan of the Jungle'.  Fun reading as a kid.